# Page is not Redirecting After Update Query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

When i submit form, it goes to the `Preferences` Controller in `setPreferences` method.

Below is my controller.

```
public function index(){
    $data['page_title'] = 'Preferences';
    $this->load->view('admin/common/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/common/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('admin/preferences');
    $this->load->view('admin/common/footer');

}

public function setPreferences(){
    $preferences = $_REQUEST;
    if($this->Preferences_model->set_value($preferences)){ //model is autoloading
        $this->load->view('admin/preferences');
    }
}
```

In my model, it update the table, sussessfully, but it is not redirecting again to the Prefrences page. Now it is going to blank page like this 
`http://localhost:88/personalsite/Preferences/setPreferences`

Here is my Model

```
function set_value($array){
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
        $this->db->set('value',$value);
        $this->db->where('name',$key);
        $this->db->update($this->table_name);
    }
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

How can i redirect it to the View `http://localhost:88/personalsite/Preferences/`?

I used `redirect('Preferences')` but it is still not redirecting.

Comment: What is the result when you change `$this->load->view('admin/preferences');` to `redirect('Preferences')`?

Comment: @VanTho same result, means blank page.

Comment: Maybe $this->db->affected_rows() = 0, your query is not update anything. how about adding redirect if set_value return 0?

Comment: try this `redirect('preferences ')` if not working then check your routes.php file and .htaccess file. i think your path is going to override also add else condition in `setPreferences` function like `if($this->Preferences_model->set_value($preferences)){ //model is autoloading
        $this->load->view('admin/preferences');
    }else{echo 'not redirect'; exit; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
redirect('preferences');//The function will build the URL based on your config file values(`.htaccess` and `routes.php`).
```

if not working then use else condition in `setPreferences` function like:

```
 if($this->Preferences_model->set_value($preferences)){ //model is autoloading
        $this->load->view('admin/preferences');
    }else{
        echo 'not redirect'; 
        exit; 
    }
```

also check `.htaccess` and `routes.php` file (May be your path is going to override)